# Why is xinit automatically starting xterm?

Tags: linux, xorg, x-server

When I run: `xinit [client application] -- :128 vt01 -novtswitch` I notice it starts an instance of xterm in addition to my client application. Per the man page:

```
   ...

   If no specific client program is given on the command line, xinit  will
   look  for a file in the user's home directory called .xinitrc to run as
   a shell script to start up client programs.  If no  such  file  exists,
   xinit will use the following as a default:

        xterm  -geometry  +1+1  -n  login  -display  :0

   ...
```

I assumed '*if*' was the key word here. I have specified my own client program; why is it still running xterm?

This is in a clean Mint 12/mate vm I just created.

Comment: perhaps Unix & Linux would be a better stackexchange for this

Comment: Is your ~/.xinitrc file executable?

Comment: No sir, it doesn't even exist. Nor does `/root/.xinitrc` . The only existing xinitrc on the system is `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` which is not executable; perms are 164